# The real purpose of C++20 keys_view and values_view?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

C++20 introduced [`ranges::elements_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/elements_view), which accepts a `view` of *tuple-like* values, and issues a `view` with a *value-type* of the *N*th element of the adapted `view`'s value-type, where *N* is the non-type template parameter.

In [[range.elements.view]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.elements.view), the synopsis of `ranges::elements_view` is defined as:

```
template<input_­range V, size_t N>
  requires view<V> && has-tuple-element<range_value_t<V>, N> &&
           has-tuple-element<remove_reference_t<range_reference_t<V>>, N> &&
           returnable-element<range_reference_t<V>, N>
class elements_view : public view_interface<elements_view<V, N>> {
  public:
    elements_view() = default;
    constexpr explicit elements_view(V base);
  // ...
};
```

Since the constructor of `elements_view` only contains the parameter `V`, it is impossible to initialize `elements_view` directly without specifying all template parameters ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/drsrPeaMv)):

```
std::array<std::tuple<int, float>, 5> r{};

ranges::elements_view<0>{r};  // error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
ranges::elements_view<decltype(views::all(r)), 0>{r}; // ok
views::elements<0>(r);                                // ok
```

This makes it lose the expression equivalence of other range adaptors such as `ranges::transform_view`:

```
ranges::transform_view{r, [](auto elem) { return std::get<0>(elem); }}; // ok
views::transform(r, [](auto elem) { return std::get<0>(elem); });       // ok
```

And on the basis of `elements_view`, the standard additionally introduces `keys_view` and `values_view`, which are both aliases for `elements_­view<views​::​all_­t<R>, N>`:

```
template <class R>
using keys_view = elements_view<views::all_t<R>, 0>;
template <class R>
using values_view = elements_view<views::all_t<R>, 1>;
```

The standard gives its use cases in [[range.elements#overview-example-2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.elements#overview-example-2):

```
auto historical_figures = map{
  {"Lovelace"sv, 1815},
  {"Turing"sv, 1912},
  {"Babbage"sv, 1791},
  {"Hamilton"sv, 1936}
};

auto names = keys_view{historical_figures}; 
for (auto&& name : names) {   
  cout << name << ' ';          // prints Babbage Hamilton Lovelace Turing  
}
```

which is [**not quite right**](https://godbolt.org/z/TKevhvsjE) since we cannot deduce the type of `R`, the only way to construct `keys_view` is to specify all template parameters, just like `elements_view`:

```
auto names = std::ranges::keys_view<decltype(std::views::all(historical_figures))>{historical_figures};
```

So `keys_view` and `values_view` seem to be completely useless.

What is the purpose of introducing them in the standard? Did I miss some of their useful use cases?

Comment: I think this is just an implementation issue. It *should* work, and in fact `auto names = historical_figures | std::ranges::views::keys;` compiles just fine. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/os6fdMTqo)

Comment: @cigen. I don't think it should work, at least I haven't figured out how to make it work.

Comment: What makes you think it *shouldn't* work though? The standard says it should, so I would definitely bet on a compiler bug vs a bug in the standard.

Comment: @康桓瑋: FYI: "*This makes it lose the expression equivalence of other range adaptors*" Not [the way equivalence is defined in this case](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.elements#overview-2).

Comment: @cigien. "_The standard says it should_". If you take a closer look at [range. elements#overview-2](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.elements#overview-2), you will find that `historical_figures` [cannot](https://godbolt.org/z/63E4W37d8) be initialized without specifying a `pair`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The missing `pair` issue in the example is just a bug with the example; I submitted an [editorial pull request](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/4616).

The bigger problem is with `keys_view` and `values_view`'s definitions. An LWG issue has been submitted for which I have provided a proposed resolution. The basic issue here is that

```cpp
template <class R>
using keys_view = elements_view<views::all_t<R>, 0>;
```

uses `R` only in a non-deduced context, so it can't possibly ever meet the requirement in alias template CTAD that [the arguments of the alias template be deducible from whatever type that is eventually deduced](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.class.deduct#2.3.sentence-1).

My proposed resolution simply redefines `keys_view` to be

```
template <class R>
using keys_view = elements_view<R, 0>;
```

This allows CTAD to work if you already have a view, and at least gives it a chance of working with whatever deduction guide on `elements_view` that is added later. I explored the possibility of adding such guides, but the current alias template CTAD implementations are too broken for it to be tested, so I don't feel comfortable proposing one.

With this change, you would be able to at least write

```cpp
auto names = keys_view{views::all(historical_figures)}; 
for (auto&& name : names) {   
  cout << name << ' ';          // prints Babbage Hamilton Lovelace Turing  
}
```